# Setting Colobox options from Anchor tag

Tags: colorbox

I have an .Net 4, MVC 3 site that utilizes the jquery Colorbox plug in. Everything works as expected, however, I want to allow individual `<a>` tags to customize the options of the colorbox.

On the web page is an `<a>` tag:

```
    <a class="AddNewItem" 
       href="@Url.Action("Create", "Phone", new { masterSID = ViewData["MasterSID"] })"
       cboxOptions='transition: "fade", scrolling: false, overlayClose: false, height: "100%"'>
        Add Phone
    <a>
```

In a js file I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".AddNewItem").colorbox($.extend({ title: "Add New Item" },
                                   SetCboxOptions($(this))
                             )
    );
});

function SetCboxOptions(obj) {
    var options = {};

    if ($(obj).attr("cboxOptions") != undefined) {
        var hash;
        var hashes = $(obj).attr("cboxOptions").replace(' ', '').split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split(':');
            options[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    }

    return options;
}
```

When i click the link, a pop-up windows appears with the correct form generated by calling /Phone/Create?masterSID=#.  Validation works, and submitting works.

**Here is the problem**

None of the options set in the `<a>` tag's cboxOptions attribute take effect on the Colorbox. I am using code from the Colorbox website that states this should work. Can anyone point out why it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the HTML5 data attribute to create an attribute to store your desired settings object in JSON format.  Example:

```
<a class="AddNewItem" href="@Url.Action("Create", "Phone", new { masterSID = ViewData["MasterSID"] })" data-cbox='{"transition":"fade", "height":"100%"}'>Add Phone<a>

$(".AddNewItem").each(function(){
    var settings = $(this).attr('data-cbox');

    if (settings) {
        settings = $.parseJSON(settings);
    }

    $(this).colorbox(settings || {});
});
```

Comment: That appears to have done the trick. Thanks! I'm still a bit old school and haven't brought my self up to speed on too much of HTML5. Looks like I have some homework.

I'm also new to stackoverflow and apparently I don't have enough 'Reputation' to up vote this answer. Considered it answered nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

To take Jack's answer one step further, I modified his code to allow default settings to be defined and overriden by values set in the data-cbox attribute:

```
        $(".AddNewItem").each(function () {
            var settings = $(this).attr('data-cbox');
            var defaults = $.parseJSON('{"transition":"fade","overlayClose":false,"scrolling":false,"initialWidth":"200","initialHeight":"200"}');

            if (settings) {
               settings = $.parseJSON(settings);
               settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);
            }        

            $(this).colorbox(settings || defaults);
       });
```

The `$.extend` method replaces values set in `defaults` from those defined by `settings`.  Thanks, again, Jack, for a neat and concise answer. I plan on using this pattern alot.